# Application Request Routing between IIS7 and JBoss 6 AS

Tags: iis-7, jboss6.x

We have a main web page being hosted on IIS7.  From a cursorary glance, it looks like ARR could be used to send the user to a web app hosted on JBoss 6.

On the IIS7 server, we have Basic and Windows Authentication enabled.  Whenever a user wants access to our main page, they have to provide their AD login.  My question is this: if the user clicks the link that sends them to the JBoss web app, will the session information from the login in IIS7 be passed along, when using ARR?

Basically I want a single signon, to avoid the user having to enter their AD information twice.  The web app on JBoss is ldap/AD aware, so I would like to be able to grab the username from the session, look up in AD what their roles are, and use those for permissions.  However, I'm not sure if moving from IIS7 to JBoss will persist this information.

Thanks for any help you can provide!